# row added to a table disappears instantly with jquery

Tags: jquery

I created a form with 3 text inputs to implement a table with 3 columns.
I don't understand the problem here: With my browser I can see the row created and it instantly disappears..

```
<td><button id="add">add</button></td>
```

Here's the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#add').click(function() {
    var var1 = $('#id1').val();
    var var2 = $('#id2').val();
    var var3 = $('#id3').val();

    $('.tab').append('<tr class="lign"><td>' + var1 + '</td><td>' 
        + var2 + '</td><td>' + var3 + '</td></tr>');;
});
```

Some help ? Thanks !

Comment: What's the relevant HTML?

Comment: looks like your page is refreshed on the add button click

Comment: Is this `#add` element an anchor tag?

Comment: Actually, I just have this code in my $('#add').click(function()

Comment: The html is <td><button id="add">add</button></td>

Comment: Provide online link where this behaviour can be seen

Comment: got nothing to show...

Comment: Obviously there's more to your HTML as your jQuery references several elements by ID. Please add it to your question, and then to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u7shf738/

Comment: It worked when I put the button out the form in the HTML file